# How to use Pandas library to get certain data?

Tags: python

I've got an assignment I'm getting nowhere on. I need to create a competition system that allows the user to input a competitor and the category they compete in will be returned using pandas library.

I've uploaded to csv file and I'm able to pull data from the file but have no idea how to get certain information from it to input into my code?

I tried printing code to print rows and columns but I only need what competition they compete in.

Comment: Without more information and your actual code it is a little difficult to help here. Perhaps first take a look at how to slice your data in pandas, there you will find possibilities how to get values from your table by indexing them: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#basics

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming the column name where the competition data is saved is 'Competition'.

```
import pandas as pd
    
df = pd.read_csv('name of your csv file')

comp1 = df.loc[df['Competion'] == 'name of the comp1 you want']
comp2 = df.loc[df['Competion'] == 'name of the comp2 you want']
print(comp1)
print(comp1)
```